# D3js - Line Chart with binary values

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

I'm attempting to make a line chart with binary values. Here's what I'm starting with, but I'm pretty lost as to where to go from here. I've done a bit of research and I'm struggling to put the binary concept together.

```js
// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(10);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.ms); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.binary); })
    .interpolate("step-after");

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var csv = d3.select("pre");

// Get the data
var data = d3.csv.parse(csv.text());
csv.remove();


    data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.binary = +d.binary;
        });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain([0, 520]);
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.binary; })]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);
```

```css
body { font: 12px Arial;}

path { 
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<pre>
ms,binary
20,0
40,0
60,0
80,1
100,1
120,0
140,1
160,0
180,1
200,1
220,1
240,0
260,0
280,1
300,1
320,0
340,1
360,0
380,0
400,1
420,0
440,1
460,0
480,0
500,0
520,1</pre>
```

Expected result: 
[image]

Current result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior, you are connecting each point in the dataset with a straight line. If we add circles to each data point we can see this more clearly:

[image]

And in snippet form:

```js
// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(10);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.ms); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.binary); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var csv = d3.select("pre");

// Get the data
var data = d3.csv.parse(csv.text());
csv.remove();


    data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.binary = +d.binary;
        });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain([0, 520]);
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.binary; })]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));
        
    svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("transform",function(d) {
        return "translate("+[x(d.ms),y(d.binary)]+")";
      })
      .attr("r", 2.5);

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);
```

```css
body { font: 12px Arial;}

path { 
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<pre>
ms,binary
20,0
40,0
60,0
80,1
100,1
120,0
140,1
160,0
180,1
200,1
220,1
240,0
260,0
280,1
300,1
320,0
340,1
360,0
380,0
400,1
420,0
440,1
460,0
480,0
500,0
520,1</pre>
```

But we can interpolate this curve differently. We can apply a step interpolator for our line:

**D3v3:**

```
var line = d3.svg.line().interpolate("step-after")...
```

**D3v4+**

```
var line = d3.line().curve(d3.curveStepAfter)...
```

*The current docs have a great run down of each curve [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#curves)*

There is also a step before, but given each data point represents a potential change in status, you probably want step after so that the line segment after the data point is the same as the data point itself:

[image]

And in snippet form (with the circles for demonstration):

```js
// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(10);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.ms); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.binary); })
    .interpolate("step-after");

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var csv = d3.select("pre");

// Get the data
var data = d3.csv.parse(csv.text());
csv.remove();


    data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.binary = +d.binary;
        });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain([0, 520]);
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.binary; })]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));
        
    svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("transform",function(d) {
        return "translate("+[x(d.ms),y(d.binary)]+")";
      })
      .attr("r", 2.5);

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);
```

```css
body { font: 12px Arial;}

path { 
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<pre>
ms,binary
20,0
40,0
60,0
80,1
100,1
120,0
140,1
160,0
180,1
200,1
220,1
240,0
260,0
280,1
300,1
320,0
340,1
360,0
380,0
400,1
420,0
440,1
460,0
480,0
500,0
520,1</pre>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I was looking for. Have a great day sir.